# Why would I put Maa Durga idol or building in the South West direction of a home?

Tags: meditation

I have read somewhere this is her direction but the article missed to explain why.
I am interested into detailed informations about Dikpala (guardians of directions) and method of correct worship.
Furthermore, can I perform padmasana pose and go into sadhana if I face West or South?
Will this affect me in some way?

Comment: For the normal Pujas we do (called Shanti Karmas) we should be sitting facing either East or the North. Facing the South/West is permitted only when we do Abhichara Karmas (like Marana, Ucchatana etc). The Devi Idol is best placed in the north-east quarter of the room/house. Eastern or Northern quarters are also alright. If you can do Puja in Padmasana then that is very good because it's recommended in some scriptures. But you should only face East/North.

Comment: Ok thank you. Would you explain me what is Abhichara Karmas and the so related Marana and Ucchatana?

Comment: Marana, Ucchatana, Vidheswana, Vashikarana etc. are part of Shatkarmas. You can read this -- http://www.shabarmantra.com/shat-karma/ .. For all the normal Pujas we do, we must be sitting facing either the East or the North.

Comment: Ok. My question was rising because it occurred that I have an image of Maa Durga (I think is Her) sit on a tiger and I did not know where to collocate Her in my house. For the moment, for space reason, being my home so small, I collocated the figure of Her on the East closest to North corner but in the same temple of Ganesh, because living in Europe the houses are not having the same possibilities of the Indian architecture and the things to find in order to build an altar or a temple are very limited. @Rickross let me know please thank you.

Comment: You can place the altar on the north east corner of the room. If that is not possible then place it on the north or east. No need to place it in southern part of the room or on the western part. While praying or offering worship to the image make sure that you face either the north or the east.